# serialization of object from snake case to camel case

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

I have an object which has field in lower case with an underscore

```
public class Project
{   
    public int project_id { get; set; }
    public long account_id { get; set; }
    public long user_id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public DateTime created_at { get; set; }
    public DateTime updated_at { get; set; }
}
```

I need to serialize in camel case when GET, POST, etc API hit the API.
How can I do it?

json is like:

```
{
    "project_id": 10,
    "account_id": 10,
    "user_id": 10,
    "name": "string",
    "description": "string",
    "created_at": "Date",
    "updated_at": "Date"
}
```

I want in this format:

```
{
    "projectId": 10,
    "accountId": 10,
    "userId": 10,
    "name": "string",
    "description": "string",
    "createdAt": "Date",
    "updatedAt": "Date"
}
```

Comment: And, bonus, it means you can name your properties according to C# conventions

Comment: If you're using System Text Json, the process is the same but the attribute is called JsonPropertyName. If you're using JavaScriptSerializer, upgrade

Answer (score 0):

Try using NewtonSoft's [JsonProperty attribute](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationAttributes.htm) to annotate your properties.

```cs
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class Project
{
    [JsonProperty("projectId")]
    public int project_id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("accountId")]
    public long account_id { get; set; }
    // ..
    // ..
    // ..
}
```

Comment: There are lots of classes in the project. manually in every field, I can't set JsonProperty.

Comment: Is there anything in particular blocking you from renaming these properties to the preferred Pascal-case convention of C#?

Comment: @ShashwatPrakash first of all I would use PascalCase naming for properties and only then will wonder how to convert from/to snake_case if needed. There is newtonsoft naming strategies: [snake_case](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/NamingStrategySnakeCase.htm) and [camelCase](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/NamingStrategyCamelCase.htm) that you can look into and use them